# Движение картинки при клике js/css3

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Нужно вот сделать движение картинки при клике.
Допустим есть сайт:
http://bit.ly/17wXt69
Там есть кот, выглядывающий (слева).
Как сделать чтобы он при клике спрятался под блок, и достать его было нельзя.
А когда возобновил страницу, он опять виден.
Помогите, пожалуйста!
Желательно, это все должно работать во всех браузерах.
P.S. Кот - background.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Смотрите код.
<div id="header">
<div id="header_resize">
------------
</div>
</div>


#header_resize {
background: 
url('images/home.png') no-repeat top 21.8px right 185px, url('images/dog.png') no-repeat top 30.8px right 30px, url('images/cate2.png') no-repeat top 66.8px right 855px, url('images/cate.png') no-repeat top 38.5px right 475px;
}

Здесь нет дива. Есть альтернативные методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте в css

```
#header_resize {
    /* все то что и раньше */
    transition: all 1s;
    /*тут ещё надо всякие -moz- -webkit- -o-*/
}

#header_resize.nocat {
   background: url('images/home.png') no-repeat top 21.8px right 185px, url('images/dog.png') no-repeat top 30.8px right 30px, url('images/cate2.png') no-repeat top 120px right 855px, url('images/cate.png') no-repeat top 38.5px right 475px;
}
```

в js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#header_resize').click(function() {$(this).addClass('nocat')});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

При клике куда?  например, этот код, при клике на элемент с id **cat** дает свойство данному элементу **margin-top: 100px**

```
    $("#cat").click(function(){
        this.animate({
            'margin-top':'100px', 
            'opacity':'0'
        }, 100)
    });
```